# How to print only the first match with grep

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to grep username:

```
users | grep "^\b\w*\b" -P
```

How can I get it to only show the first match with `grep`?

Comment: Why `grep`? `grep` is for searching. You seem to need either `cut` or `awk`, but the `read` builtin also seems suitable.

Comment: this work as @peterph proposed ^\w*\b. Are cut or sed/awk more convinient? my case is simple. i can use myVar=\`users | grep -o "^\w*\b"\`, no?

Comment: Compare them: `users | cut -d' ' -f1`, `users | sed 's/\s.*//'`, `users | awk '$0=$1'`. If you want to store it in a variable, using `bash`: `read myVar blah < <(users)` or `read myVar blah <<< $(users)`.

Comment: @Yurij73 the difference lies mostly in the execution time. with `read` you don't spawn a new process. If you do this many times, you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Does it better use awk?  
                #!/bin/bash
                ( users|awk '$0=$1' )>file;
                read myVar <file; 
                rm -f file;
                echo $myVar;

Comment: Related: [How to get the first word of a string?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65932/21471)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want return just the first word and want to do this with `grep` and your `grep` happens to be a recent version of GNU `grep`, you probably want the `-o` option. I believe you can do this without the `-P` and the `\b` at the beginning is not really necessary. Hence: `users | grep -o "^\w*\b"`.

Yet, as @manatwork mentioned, shell built-in `read` or `cut`/`sed`/`awk` seem to be more appropriate (particularly once you get to the point you'd need to do something more).

Comment: Alternative syntax: `grep -o "[^ ]*"`

Comment: @kenorb which is a bit different actually (but will work in most cases).

Comment: Use `grep -oE ...` for regular expression

Answer (score 51):

To show only the first match with `grep`, use `-m` parameter, e.g.:

```
grep -m1 pattern file
```

> `-m num`, `--max-count=num`
>
> Stop reading the file after num matches.

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me.the first match catch with:

```
users | grep -m 1 "^\b\w*\b"
```

and the last match catch with

```
users | grep "^\b\w*\b" |tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `grep`? The `grep` command is for searching. You seem to need either `cut` or `awk`, but the read builtin also seems suitable.

Compare them:

```
users | cut -d' ' -f1
users | sed 's/\s.*//'
users | awk '$0=$1'
```

If you want to store it in a variable, using bash:

```
read myVar blah < <(users)
```

or:

```
read myVar blah <<< $(users).
```

<sup>Above answer based on [@manatwork comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/grep-the-only-first-word-from-output-with-grep-p/57879#comment79772_57876).</sup>