# How to get the first word of a string?

Tags: bash, string

When I `echo *`  I get the following output:

```
file1 file2 file3 ...
```

What I want is to pick out the first word. How can I proceed?

Comment: @mattdm Using `ls` won't work if one of the filenames contains a blank.

Comment: How do you define _word_? If the first file is `Sunset on a beach.jpg`, should it be `Sunset` or the whole file name? What about `Sea, sex and sun.ogg`? `Sea`, `Sea,` or the whole file name?

Comment: @mattdm `ls | head -1` gives me random things like `a.patch     p.py` which is not the first word and not even files in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 159):

You can pipe it through awk and make it echo the first word

```
echo * | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'
```

or you cut the string up and select the first word:

```
echo *  | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1
```

or you pipe it thorugh sed and have it remove everything but the first word

```
echo * | head -n1 | sed -e 's/\s.*$//'
```

Added the `| head -n1` to satisfy nitpickers. In case your string contains newlines `| head -n1` will select the first line first before the important commands select the first word from the string passed to it.

Comment: The would return the first word of every line, not the first word.

Comment: i wonder how many lines `echo *` generates

Comment: That depends how many files have newline characters in their name or depending on the environment or how bash was compiled or whether some file called `-e` or `-ee`... appears in the list, how many time `\n` appears in a file name. If there's a file called `-n`, it might not even return any line at all...

Comment: Well, we're still talking bash and
1. usually bash will not pass a string with newlines as one string with new lines
2. it's very hard and unusual (impossible?) to have a newline in a filename
3. a \n in a filename will show up as a \n
4. 3 holds for filenames starting with -
5. even when called with -n or -e echo will open stdout and close it when it's done so of course it will return a line, and at least one string, for that matter
6. i edited my advice to at least take care of the multiline problem

Comment: All 5 points are false. Try in an empty dir: `touch '$a\nb' 'a\nb'; env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo bash -c 'echo * | wc -l'` (`xpg_echo` is enabled wherever `bash` is required to be Unix conformant). And in another empty directory: `touch ./-n; bash -c 'echo * | wc -l'`. A line is a sequence of characters terminated by a newline character. If `echo` doesn't output a newline character, it doesn't output any line. Behavior of text utilities like `cut`, `awk` or `sed` is unspecified if the input has extra characters after the last newline character and behavior varies across implementations.

Comment: `head` not needed with `awk 'NR==1{print $1}` or `awk '{print $1;exit}'` and `sed -n '1s/\s.*//p'` (don't need $ because greedy)

Comment: I found that `sed` includes the whole line and `awk` includes `\u00a0` in the end of an extracted word. If you have `node` installed, here is a clever command you can use to extract the first word: `echo * | xargs node -e 'console.log(process.argv[1])'` ([0] being node exec itself). Maybe it helps someone, who hacks some cli tools.

Answer (score 59):

Assuming a posixy shell (`/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` can do this)

```
all=$(echo *)
first=${all%% *}
```

The construct `${all%% *}` is an example of *substring removal*. The `%%` means delete the longest match of `*` (a space followed by anything) from the right-hand end of the variable `all`. You can read more about string manipulation [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

This solution assumes that the separator is a space. If you're doing this with file names then any with spaces will break it.

Comment: Nice one. But I liked the simple and more non-hacky other version with `head` and `cut`

Comment: IMO, head, cut & sed are less simple.  Why spawn another tool when builtin parameter substitution does the job efficiently.  This answer is most efficient and most portable way to pick off the first word of a list of space-separated words (which is all the OP asked for).

Comment: @Juan , first how is builtin substitution efficient - not intended as rhetorical, but who knows what the actual complexity is. Second, unlikely, but if `echo *` were a stream or some # of lines approaching infinity, wouldn't this be a particularly fun way to OOM your box? I don't if you can OOM of an assignment like this, as in does any shell provide constraints (like buffer + block writes to memory), but my guess is that there arent and that you definitely can write to all available memory on a casual, nothing to see here,  assignment.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you really want the first *filename* and not the first *word*, here's a way that doesn't break on whitespace:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*)
printf '%s\n' "${files[0]}"
```

Comment: First word would be easy, too: `files=($(echo *))`

Comment: It would break on "-n", "-e", "-ne", "-Enenene"..., and depending on how `bash` was compiled or the environment, possibly on backslash characters, though.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, you'd need to disable globbing. Like: `text=$(echo *); set -f; files=($text)`, otherwise more wildcards could be expanded.

Comment: I also find that easy to use `echo * | cut -d ' ' -f 1` is that good practice ?

Comment: and `files=$(echo *); echo ${files%% *}`

Comment: @Oddant - the ${a%% *} is a CHARM, thank you!

Comment: @memnoch_proxy It will break on filenames containing whitespace, use it with caution.

Comment: @ChrisDown good point, but otherwise it's very useful for pulling a date string name off string output, like I could turn "2013:15:21 01:05:13" into 2013-15-21 using b=${a%% *}; c=${b/:/-}

Comment: @Oddant: ${files%% *} saved the day! Thanks!

Comment: Portability note: this method is full of bash-isms.

Comment: @Juan This post is explicitly *about* bash, it has the "bash" tag

Comment: Or just `$files` because bash automatically uses element [0]

Answer (score 10):

You can use the positional parameters

```
set -- *
echo "$1"
```

Comment: Be aware that this will destroy any other arguments to your script, unless run in an auxiliary scope. It will also expand to `*` if there are no files in the directory.

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` would handle that

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
echo * | grep -o "^\w*\b"
```

Creds to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57879/3920

Comment: Unless the first filename is something like `-n` , `-e`, `-ne`, `-en`, etc. On some platforms.

Comment: I like this one, which can catch all rows with the first word.  I am using NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"

Answer (score 3):

Check one of the following alternatives:

```
$ FILE=($(echo *))
$ FILE=$(echo * | grep -o "^\S*")
$ FILE=$(echo * | grep -o "[^ ]*")
$ FILE=$(find . -type f -print -quit)
```

Then you can print it via `echo $FILE`.

See also: [`grep` the only first word from output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57876/21471)

Answer (score 1):

Getting the whole first file name:

```
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s\000' * | grep -z -m 1 '^..*$'
printf '%s\000' * | ( IFS="" read -r -d "" var; printf '%s\n' "$var" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to list all the file names as an array, and then index the array for the first element:

```
STRARRAY=($(echo *))
FIRST=${STRARRAY[0]}
```

Comment: Already in Chris Down's answer and equivalent to kenorb's but you actually need only `$STRARRAY` because bash automatically selects [0]